# DevExpress Horizontal GridControl

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I would like to know. How can I make WPF GridControl like it.

[image]

Comment: That looks a lot detail from a master detail displayed in a regular Grid.  What custom behavior do you need that is not available that you need to make a custom control?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a regular DataGrid.

Then add a DataTemplateSelector to handle displaying the different types of data in the second column.

I did something similar with Images and Buttons as an example. It was a while ago when I was first learning but it still might help you.
http://www.wpfsharp.com/2010/04/08/how-to-add-a-dynamic-image-andor-a-dynamic-button-to-a-datagrid-row-using-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-and-a-datatemplateselector/